# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project identity model returns empty

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm learning dotnet6 and this is my first ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project. It's just been 3/4 days I'm learning so it can be an easy solution.
I'm trying to get Users to a list but the list seems empty but there are registered users in database.

This is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<User>

@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<div class="container p-3">
    <div class="row pt-4">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2 class="text-primary">User List</h2>
        </div>
    
</div>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                UserName
            </th>

            <th>
                Email
            </th>
                           
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var obj in Model)
         {
            <tr>
                <td width="50%">
                    @obj.UserName
                </td>
                <td width="30%">
                    @obj.Email
                </td>

            </tr>

        }
```

This is the model class `User`:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string? Email { get; set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

`Dbset` of `User` in `ApplicationDbContext` is

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

Also I've changed `AspNetUser` table name to `Users`.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>(entity =>
    {
       entity.ToTable("Users");
    });
}
```

UserController code:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<UserController> _logger;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public UserController(ApplicationDbContext db, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, ILogger<UserController> logger)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _db = db;
    }

    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<User> objUserList = _db.Users;
        return View(objUserList);
    }
}
```

I've done login and register methods, also with `IdentityUser` and they both work.

I have the same codes for another `Categories` model and it shows categories without any problem but can't do the same with `Users`.

Categories page:

[image: Categories page]

User List page:

[image: User List]

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your Index method of UserController to verify either you are getting data from db or not.

Comment: To get all Identtiy users stored in the database use "userManager.Users". Refer this [link](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-create-read-update-delete-users/).

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is my working code, I hope you register everything correctly in the Program.cs

```
 private UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
        private RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;
        private readonly WorkshopProContext _cs;


        public UsersAdmin(UserManager<ApplicationUser> usrMgr, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, WorkshopProContext cs)
        {
            userManager = usrMgr;
            this.roleManager = roleManager;
            _cs = cs;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(userManager.Users.ToList());
        }
```